# How do I call a Form's class function or access its property from a conditional formatting expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, expression, conditional-formatting, ms-access-2003

Having the following code on a Form class in Access 2003:

```vb
Public currentId As Integer

Private Sub Form_Current()
  Me.currentId = Me.id
  ' The following works fine
  Debug.Print Forms!my_form_name.currentId
End Sub
```

...and an unbound textbox in the same continuous form (created in design view), how do I access the `.currentId` property from a conditional formatting expression?

I want to use the unbound textbox to highlight the record that is currently selected by comparing the form's `.currentId` value with the actual `[id]` of its own record.

Some expressions I've tried:

```vb
[id] = Me.currentId
[id] = Me!currentId
[id] = Me.Form.currentId
[id] = Forms!my_form_name.currentId
[id] = Forms!my_form_name!currentId
[id] = Forms!my_form_name!Form.[currentId]
[id] = Forms!my_form_name!Form!currentId
[id] = Forms!my_form_name!Form[currentId]
[id] = Forms!my_form_name![currentId]
[id] = Forms![my_form_name].[currentId]
[id] = Forms![my_form_name]![currentId]
```

...etc., etc., etc. Any variant I could think of, basically.

I've tried creating a `Public Function getCurrentId()` as well, but that didn't get me anywhere either. It even complained when I added parentheses in the expression, like this:

```
[id] = Forms!my_form_name.getCurrentId()
```

...which I should perhaps take as a hint that these more complex expressions are probably not allowed for conditional formatting expressions.

So, am I missing something? Or is it indeed simply not possible to reference anything other than current record fields in these conditional formatting expressions?

---

One other detail that might be important to mention, is that Access 2003 localizes the `Forms` part to `Formulieren` in the conditional formatting expression dialog, in the Dutch version I am using.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an hidden unbound text box called say txtCurrRec on your detail line, set using the on current event by

```
Me.txtCurrRec = Me.Id
```

Then all you need in the conditional formatting is

```
Expression is [txtCurrRec] = [YourIDField]
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I did, for now, as well. :-) Would still like to know what syntax is allowed in conditional formatting though and/or why my attempts failed.

Comment: Out of interest did you try simply [CurrentID] = [ID] ?

Comment: That might just be the one thing I did not attempt, no. :-) I'll give that a shot sometime later on today, if I'm working on the project again, and tell you whether it worked.

Comment: Okay, I just tried it, but it didn't work, unfortunately. I think it has something to do with the fact that it's a kind of global property of the class and not a field of the current record. I suspect conditional formatting expression only allow you to access properties in the scope of its own record, or something to that extend.